# eclipse: Managing projects

Tags: eclipse

I have tried to find these out, but could not.

1. Can eclipse open all dependent projects? I have a maven project with dependencies. Can eclipse open dependent projects also? (or at least try to, as some of the dependencies are external and would have no sources/project)
2. As a workaround to the above possible limitation in eclipse, i have created working sets and added projects to them. But could not see an option to open all projects in a working set one one shot. Is there such an option?

(Using eclipse Kepler)

Answer (score 3):

1. Selecting this option should do it for you. 
   [image: eclipse_pref]
2. mark all project, right click and select open project

Comment: No this is not what I was looking for. This works only if referenced projects are added explicitly. I want to eclipse to recognize dependent from pom and open them automatically.